# extract data of interest from array object

Tags: javascript

i am trying to extract specific data from an array object using keys but all the data gets returned? why is that? i want to print to the console all the values corresponding to the key `genestart` only

```
for (var i=0; i<genedata.matches.length;i++){                                                                                                         
        var arr = genedata.matches[i];                                                                                                                    
        for (var key in arr){                                                                                                                             
            var attrName=key;                                                                                                                             
            var attrValue = arr[key];                                                                                                                     
            //console.log(attrValue);                                                                                                                     
            if (attrName='genestart'){                                                                                                                    
              console.log(attrValue);                                                                                                                     

            }                                                                                                                                             
        }                                                                                                                                                 
    }
```

Comment: Please provide an example of what genedata looks like

Comment: 0: {…}
​​​
genename: "thrL"
​​​
genesrc: "NCBI_GP:AAN78501.1"
​​​
genestart: 190
​​​
genestop: 255
​​​
genestrand: 1
​​​
productid: "AAN78501.1"
​​​
productname: "Thr operon leader peptide"

Answer (score 2):

Your if statement is not a comparison but an assignment. Change = to ==

Comment: No problem! Please approve the answer if that fixed it for you.